# Prove or disprove that $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff the inclusion $\operatorname{int}_Yf[U]\subseteq f[\operatorname{int}_X U]$ holds.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, examples-counterexamples

> **Definition**
>
> A function $f$ from a topological space $X$ to a topological space $Y$ is continuous at $x_0\in X$ if for any neighborhood $V_0$ of $f(x_0)$ there exists a neighborhood $U_0$ of $x_0$ such that the inclusion
> $$
> f[U_0]\subseteq V_0
> $$
> holds. In particular $f$ is said continuous at $X$ if it is continuous at any $x\in X$.

So with respect this definition it is well know that $f$ is continuous if and only if the preimmage of and open set $V$ of $Y$ is open in $X$ so that the inclusion
$$
f^{-1}[\operatorname{int}_Y V]\subseteq\operatorname{int}_X f^{-1}[V]
$$
holds. Conversetly if the last inclusion holds then effectively also the inclusion
$$
f^{-1}[\operatorname{int}_Y V]\subseteq\operatorname{int}_X f^{-1}[V]\subseteq f^{-1}[V]
$$
holds so that when $V$ is open we conclude that
$$
f^{-1}[V]=\operatorname{int}_X f^{-1}[V]
$$
that is the preimage of open set is open and thus $f$ is continuous.

Now putting
$$
V:=f[U]
$$
for any $U\in\mathcal P(X)$ we observe that
$$
f^{-1}\big[\operatorname{int}_Yf[U]\big]\subseteq\operatorname{int}_Xf^{-1}\big[f[U]\big]
$$
so that if $f$ was **surjective** then
$$
\operatorname{int}_Yf[U]=f\Big[f^{-1}\big[\operatorname{int}_Yf[U]\big]\Big]\subseteq f\Big[\operatorname{int}_Xf^{-1}\big[f[U]\big]\Big]=f[\operatorname{int}_X U]
$$

So I would like to prove or disprove if the last inclusion holds even when $f$ is **not** surjective and **in particular** I would like to prove that the following statement are equivalent

1. $f$ is continuous
2. $\operatorname{int}_Y f[U]\subseteq f[\operatorname{int}_X U]$ for any $U\in\mathcal P(X)$
3. $f^{-1}[\operatorname{int}_Y V]\subseteq\operatorname{int}_X f^{-1}[V]$ for any $V\in\mathcal P(Y)$
4. $f^{-1}[V]$ is open in $X$ when $V$ is open in $Y$
5. $f^{-1}[V]$ is closed in $X$ when $V$ is closed in $Y$
6. $f[\operatorname{cl}_X U]\subseteq\operatorname{cl}_Y f[U]$ for any $U\in\mathcal P(X)$
7. $\operatorname{cl}_X f^{-1}[V]\subseteq f^{-1}[\operatorname{cl}_Y V]$ for any $V\in\mathcal P(Y)$

However the implication
$$
3\to4\to6\to6\to7\to1
$$
is proved in many topology texts so that effectively I ask to prove (or disprove) only the implication
$$
1\to 2\to 3
$$
I point out that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2384799/736008) there is a similar question where is proved that if the inclusion $2$ holds when $f$ is surjective that $f$ is continuous so that it seem to me that this prove that the inclusion does **not** hold when $f$ is **not** continuous but I am quit hesitant about now so that I thought to put a specific question where I ask clarifications.

So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Try to find examples where $f$ is discontinuous, not surjective, and $\operatorname{int}_Y f[ U]\subseteq f[\operatorname{int}_X U]$ holds for all $U$.

Comment: @GEdgar Sorry, but it seem to me that the inclusion $$f^{-1}[\operatorname{int}_Y V]\subseteq\operatorname{int}_X f^{-1}[V]$$ holds only if $f$ is continuous: do I am wrong?

Comment: I corrected my comment.

Comment: @GEdgar Okay, so by your comment I infer that the inclusion does not generally holds: so I am working for a counterexample bearing in mind what you suggested now.

Comment: Does "neigborhood" mean "open neigborhood"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a general map property $2.$ is not related to continuity.

- $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2, f(x) = 
  \begin{cases}
  (x,0) & x  \le 0 \\
  (x,1) & x > 0
  \end{cases}
  $ satisfies $2.$ because $\operatorname{int} f(A) = \emptyset$ for all $A$.But $f$ is not continuous.
- $f: I \times I \to I, f(s,t) = s$, is continuous. It does not satisfy $2.$ because for the diagonal $\Delta \subset I \times I$ we have  $f(\operatorname{int}\Delta)) = f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$, but $\operatorname{int} f(\Delta) = \operatorname{int} I = I$.

The implication $1. \Rightarrow 3.$ is easy to verify:

Let $x_0 \in f^{-1}[\operatorname{int}_Y V]$. Then $\operatorname{int}_Y V$ is an open neighborhood of $f(x_0)$ and there exists an open neighborhood $U_0$ of $x_0$ such that $f(U_0) \subset \operatorname{int}_Y V$. Then clearly $f(U_0) \subset V$ which means $U_0 \subset  f^{-1}[V]$. Thus $x_0 \in \operatorname{int}_X f^{-1}[V]$.

Comment: Okay, all clear now: question upvoted and approved. Thanks very much for your assistance!!!