# How to prove the question about the continuity of map by using interior of sets?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces and $f:X\to Y$ be a **surjective** map. If $intf(A)\subset f(intA)$ for any subset $A\subset X$, then $f$ is continuous.  Here $int A$ means the interior of $A$

Can someone prove the claim or give some hints on it? Many Thanks!

The following solution is not true: Let $V\subset Y$ is open, noting that $V=f(f^{-1}(V))$, we have
$$V=intV=intf(f^{-1}(V))\subset f(int(f^{-1}(V))),$$
which implies that $f^{-1}(V)\subset int f^{-1}(V)$. So, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open and $f$ is continuous. The problem is: for a set $B\subset X$, $f^{-1}(f(B))=B$ is not necessarily true since we don't know whether $f$ is injective.

Comment: This should follow directly from your hypothesis and the definition of continuity.

Comment: What did you try? https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I just found the answer here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384799/let-fx-to-y-be-a-surjective-map-such-that-textintfa-subset-f-textin?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This theorem is wrt surjective continuous maps. The idea is that f preserves interiors, where the interior of the image of a set is contained in the image of the interior of that set.

We prove this:

Assume intf(A)⊂f(intA) for all A⊂X.
We want to show f is continuous.
So take any open U⊂Y. We need to show f^-1(U) is open in X.
But f^-1(U) = f^-1(intf(f^-1(U))) ⊂ int(f^-1(U)) by the assumption
So f^-1(U) is open, and f is continuous.

Key is using the assumption on f to show that f^-1 preserves open sets. Hence, continuity follows easily.

In general, any time you have a map that "preserves some topological property" in this way, it's a good sign that continuity will follow. Preserving open sets, closed sets, interiors, etc. are common ways this happens.

Comment: @ Anon Imus Tnaks. How to get $ f^-1(intf(f^-1(U))) ⊂ int(f^-1(U))$? Would you like to present the details? Many thanks.

Comment: Sure, here are the details:

f^-1(intf(f^-1(U))) = f^-1(f(int(f^-1(U)))) by definition of intf
⊂ int(f^-1(U)) by assumption (intf(A) ⊂ f(intA) for all A)

So we have:
f^-1(U) = f^-1(intf(f^-1(U))) ⊂ int(f^-1(U))

Which means f^-1(U) is open, and f is continuous.

The key is just using the assumption that f preserves interiors (intf(A) ⊂ f(intA)) to relate f^-1(intf(f^-1(U))) and int(f^-1(U)), then the fact that the interior of a set contains the set gives us what we need.